# How To Create Cumulative Variable in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Maybe is a stupid question but i can`t find a example to:

```
CurrencyVar x;
if(x=0) then
   x:= {saldo}+{CtaCte.Haber}-{CtaCte.Debe}
else
   x:=x+{CtaCte.Haber}-{CtaCte.Debe}
```

Currently this calculated field fails. The varaible x always remains at zero

Comment: Hi Guillermo - Is it possible {saldo}, {CtaCte.Haber} or-{CtaCte.Debe} could ontain NUKL vaues? One easy way to check is at the top of the formula editor, instead of exceptions for NULL use default value for NULL.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy In this case it is not possible since these values ​​have default zero in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeking examples I had saved I found that to do this I must do as follows:

```
CurrencyVar x;
if(PreviousIswNull({CtaCte.Haber})) then
   x:= {saldo}+{CtaCte.Haber}-{CtaCte.Debe}
else
   x:=x+{CtaCte.Haber}-{CtaCte.Debe}
```

This works because the first record the previous value will always be null